# In Jenkins pipeline, how can I generate a concise report from the job outputs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline created that is a series of Powershell jobs in various parallel stages. Whilst the jobs are in stages, there is no dependency between them (I only split them into stages in order to avoid conflicts).

I want to gather a report from every job but at a pipeline level. Each job will output a single line of text, but the full report needs to be at pipeline level. The current pipeline console output just says that the job is starting and stopping, there is no additional output brought in from the jobs. I've considered the following;

1. I have seen the stash/unstash option, but that seems to be at a file level and I'm not sure how to use that to generate a report.
2. I can see the echo command in pipeline, but can't see a way of passing a string/variable from the job to the pipeline.
3. I tried taking the pipeline 'WORKSPACE' variable to pass to the job so the job can write directly to a single file, but the variable didn't work (and I've no idea if this is violating some unwritten 'rule' of pipelines).

How can I get a single line of text, from each job in a pipeline, out to a single text file?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   I can see the echo command in pipeline, but can't see a way of passing a string/variable from the job to the pipeline.
>   Blockquote

if you use powershell you can use write-host or -- verbose

> Blockquote
>   I tried taking the pipeline 'WORKSPACE' variable to pass to the job so the job can write directly to a single file, but the variable didn't work (and I've no idea if this is violating some unwritten 'rule' of pipelines).
>   Blockquote

İf you want to use jenkins variable, you have to use "%" symbol.

%WORKSPACE%

Comment: Write-Host just writes to the console output of the job, not the console output of the pipeline. I'll try the % symbol shortly.